# How To Style ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="15" Margin="15" BorderBrush="LightBlue" Background="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <view:Config />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Border>
```

This is the code I've written in XAML. However, it doesn't appear to affect anything.

There are so many posts on SO with similar questions but all of their response are "use `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`" which I've done :S Such as [There is no ListBox.SelectionMode="None", is there another way to disable selection in a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398559/there-is-no-listbox-selectionmode-none-is-there-another-way-to-disable-select) and [WPF, XAML: How to style a ListBoxItem using binding on property of ListBox ItemsSource object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305157/wpf-xaml-how-to-style-a-listboxitem-using-binding-on-property-of-listbox-items)

What I would expect is that there is no background, no border and the item is not focusable.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Redefine the `ControlTemplate` of your `ListBoxItem`. The sample code below uses a *redish* color just to make the point, but you can just replace it with `Transparent`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication235.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication235"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <x:Array x:Key="SampleData" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
        <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Item 3</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Item 4</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Item 5</sys:String>
    </x:Array>

    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1FFF0000"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SampleData}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}"
             Height="150" Margin="0" Width="250"/>

</Grid>
```

[image]

and using a `Transparent` background, no focus, no highlighting, as required:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use style in resource like:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#D8D8D8"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="400"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        <!--and so on whatever you want...-->
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

And remove code like:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And don't use any property in listBox which is used in style, other wise it will not behave which is described in style.